# What does "indicative" mean for the literature review

Tags: publications, literature-review

One reviewer of my paper commented the following:

> The authors should clearly state that the literature they have
>   included in the introduction **is indicative** (both in the case of
>   experimental measurements and molecular simulation of ILs) and
>   redirect to some recent review articles.

I don't know what does he mean. I don't know If he expected that I add some introductory sentences before reviewing literature like (bold part):

> **Several experiments have recently been performed in order to understand the underlying dynamics of ILS, including XXX.** ZZZ et al. [8] obtained the viscosities of the ILs XXX and YYY in a wide temperature range. Moreover, ZZZ and KKK [9] recently published atmospheric pressure self-diffusion coefficients of MMM tetrafluoroborates and NNN in the temperature range of 40-90 ℃.

However, in a previous paragraph I mentioned an introductory about ILs in General and not XXX in particular:

> In the literature, experimental and theoretical methods have been employed to obtain the properties of ILs. Experimental analyses such as IR, H and F NMR spectra, polarizing optical microscopy, differential scanning calorimetry, and UV-vis spectra have been used to determine the properties of ILs [5-7].

Comment: That does seem an odd word choice. You'd expect it to say "is indicative **of** XYZ". Possibly they mean that the papers you're citing are just a small part of the existing literature, and you need to make that clear in the introduction.

Answer (score 7):

Your reviewer might be Italian! In Italian, you can say that something is just "indicative" (or *indicativo*) if it is only there to give you a rough idea.
You can probably just state that your literature review is not exhaustive.

Some examples of [*a titolo indicativo*](http://dictionary.reverso.net/italian-english/a%20titolo%20indicativo)

Comment: It is what I first thought. Italy here.

Comment: It isn't only an Italian expression. I've heard that usage of "indicative" in the French-speaking world, also.